# !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!bitmap list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap

I have this problem. I have a list that displays some parsed images. When i click over a list item i get the error in the logcat `!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`. I saw that could be a size problem of bitmap and i found this code:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 960, 960, false);
```

so in my case:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data 
                //Elements img = document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]");
                // Locate the src attribute
                for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
                    String ImgSrc = img.attr("src");
                    // Download image from URL
                    InputStream is = new java.net.URL(ImgSrc).openStream();

                    Bitmap resizedbitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, true);
                    //add Bitmap to an array
                    bitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
                 }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

of course doesn't work because my bitmap is an `ArrayList<Bitmap>` so i get the error in `createScaledBitmap`. Three simply questions;

1) Is this the problem?

2) Is the right place to put that code?

3) How can i solve having `ArrayList<Bitmap>`?

thanks

Comment: A failed binder transaction will only come from IPC, and there is no IPC in your code snippet. Are you packaging this bitmap in an `Intent` extra, or trying to send it to an app widget, or anything like that?

Comment: FYI, IPC is inter-process communication. Different types of components are communicated  for instance by means of  Intents, Binders, etc. The CommonsWare question is the first that we need to know. We cannot imagine in what kind of situation you are, or the rest of the surrounding code

Comment: Thanks for the answers..anyway..what I'm trying to do is passing the bitmap in another activity..but if I click in a item of the list nothing works and appear that error in the log cat.